# Craft won't install

Tags: install

When I browse to the public index file, I get a message that says:

> Page not found

I already configured the database and the folders have write permissions.

What else should I check?

Comment: Is it an Apache styled 404 page or a Craft styled one? What happens when you try to run the installer (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing#step-5-run-the-installer)?  Did you remember to rename your htaccess file to .htaccess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try this?

"If you’re getting a 404, your server might not be configured to redirect would-be 404’s to index.php correctly. Try going to http://example.com/index.php/admin or http://example.com/index.php?p=admin instead."

Comment: Hi @user2381778, can you elaborate a little more on what exactly solved your problem? The examples provided by MISC are a workaround, not really a permanent solution.

Comment: just add /admin like this http://example.com/index.php/admin

Comment: I have this same issue. How would I configure the server to redirect would-be 404s to index.php?

Comment: Ah. My issue was related to my virtual host settings. I had a directory path wrong so the host was not reading my .htaccess file at all. http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/url-rewrites-not-working-return-apache-404s