# Control Panel URLs being rewritten to use index.php?p=admin/

Tags: control-panel, url, error

All of our control panel URLs are being rewritten to show index.php?p=admin/***

While this isn't a problem in itself we can't determine why it's happening when the frontend of the website itself is writing the URLs cleanly and correctly without the index.php?p=

We have in our .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

There are no other Rewrites happening.

A possibly related issue we're seeing is that there are no entries, assets or categories listing in the control panel. Looking through the logs I can see the following

```
2015/09/22 16:55:23 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.400] exception 'Craft\HttpException' with message 'Param “elementType” doesn’t exist.' in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php:586
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/controllers/BaseElementsController.php(50): Craft\HttpRequestService->getRequiredParam('elementType')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/controllers/ElementIndexController.php(68): Craft\BaseElementsController->getElementType()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(281): Craft\ElementIndexController->init()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(784): CWebApplication->runController('elementIndex/ge...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(276): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/httpdocs/index.php(40): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
#8 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php?p=admin/actions/elementIndex/getElements
HTTP_REFERER=http://mysite.org/index.php?p=admin/entries/pages
---
2015/09/22 16:55:23 [error] [application] Param “elementType” doesn’t exist.

******************************************************************************************************
```

We do have PATH_INFO installed and enabled on the server.

Craft Pro 2.4.2692

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like a dupe? Try this: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/url-rewrites-not-working-return-apache-404s/4387#4387

Comment: Hi @BradBell I don't think it's the same problem. My .htaccess file is being used (if I put invalid apache config settings in there it breaks the whole site). Also I'm only seeing problems in the Control Panel, the sites front-end is working a treat!

Comment: You sure there's no parent `.htaccess` file above Craft's? The rules will inherit from each other.

Comment: My bad, I was editing a staged version of the general.php config file. Adding 'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true fixed the URLs (must have cached false at some point). We're still experiencing trouble loading entries/assets/categories in the CP though. Any thoughts?

Comment: @BradBell Shall I re-ask the 2nd part to the question about not seeing entry/asset/category lists in the CP as a new question?

Comment: The only reason you'd get that error is if something required was missing from `$_POST`, so I'd still suspect some `.htaccess` weirdness. Or maybe mod_security or Suhosin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,` to your `general.php` settings?

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#omitScriptNameInUrls

Comment: Hi @dgrebb, I've set that to true aswell as 'usePathInfo' => true but not seeing any change.

Comment: Hi @dgrebb, you were right about the omitScriptNameInUrls setting. That fixed the URLs but we're still seeing issues with no entry/asset/category lists loading in the CP. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the 2nd part of the original question, whereby no entry, asset, category or user lists were display, this turned out to be a post_max_size issue in the php.ini config. It had been incorrectly set to 64**MB** rather than 64**M**.

Comment: Interesting find. Glad you got it sorted!