# Clean install - Service Unavailable message at setup

Tags: install, installation

Folks:

I installed CraftCMS. All files are uploaded, chmod done, and everything else. I visit the page http://example.com/admin to go through setup and I get the message "Service Unavailable. Our site is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

- I checked .htaccess and the config file. All is well.
- I changed isSystemOn from "null" to "true". Same message.
- I contacted my host to see if Craft will run on the server. All
  requirements are met.

Since this is a Craft message it seems pretty clear that the database is being connected to but nothing is happening. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Try the solution [outlined here...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1220/45)

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issues. Found the problem was in the .htaccess file. 
Without code fixes, visit http://example.com/index.php/admin
instead of http://example.com/admin

Then fix your htaccess file later.